# Resultset exhausted

Tags: java, database-connection, resultset

Showing ResultSet exhausted on second time i call this method . First time no error. Showing error at `obj[i][j] = rs.getString(1);`

```
public static void createTableModel(ResultSet rs) {

    try {
        rs.first();
        while(rs.next()) {
            count++;
        }
        String [][] obj;
        obj = new String [count][3];
        rs.first();
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                  for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if(j == 0) {  
                        obj[i][j] = rs.getString(1);
                    }
                    else if(j == 1) {
                        obj[i][j] = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(2));
                    }
                    else if(j == 2) {
                        obj[i][j] = rs.getString(6);
                    }
                  }
                  rs.next();
                }
        GlobalVariables.table1 = new DefaultTableModel(obj,
        new String [] {
            "Name", "Age", "License No"
        }
    );
}
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I faced the same problem once. I then used another Data Structure to copy the values from RS and use it afterwards. I don't know why that happens though.

Comment: you created another string object to copy data ?

Comment: I stored the complete result from `resultset` which is returned form query in an `arraylist` and then i used that `arraylist`.

Comment: What is the result set type? If it's TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, this is expected...

Comment: i will check that now.

Comment: ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE

Using this it can call .first() function so i used this.

Comment: Have you tried closing all the DB connections and the resultSet after the use?

Comment: Also, to notify a particular user, use "@" + name , so possibly sir @JonSkeet isn't notified.

Comment: @joeyrohan i tried closing the resultset but still showing exhausted resultset

Comment: @JonSkeet I used ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE.

Comment: Check with the method `if(rs.hasNext()) {/* do stuff */}` exhausted resultSet is thrown when you access the resultSet when it is already empty.

Comment: I converted resultset to an list<arraylist<string>> now problem is solved. I can execute it many times. Thank you for your help. thnks @ADi

Comment: @JithinSebastian You're welcome! The problem behind that problem is  `resultset` can be accessed only once per query. You have to re-run the query if you want to use it again. Again, I am not that sound behind the technicality of this matter. That's why I came up with this trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

I converted resultset to an list>

```
List<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
                do{
                ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<>(6);
                int i = 1;
                while (i <= 6) {
                    row.add(GlobalVariables.data3.getString(i++));
                }
                result.add(row);
                }while (GlobalVariables.data3.next());
```

It solved the problem. I still don't know why it showed the error exhausted resultset.